# XSL Convert Scientific notation to number

Tags: xml, xslt, timecodes

I'm using XSL 2.0. I have the following `$intTOTAL` which I'm converting to milliseconds. But the output of this is in scentific notation. How do i convert this to a normal number without scientific notation

```
<xsl:variable name="intTotal" select="((number($timeINTSEC)*60)*1000 + number($timeINTMSEC))"/>
<TEST><xsl:value-of select="number($intTotal)"/></TEST>
```

Here is the output i'm getting

```
 <TEST>1.14E6</TEST>
```

Comment: Use `xs:decimal` or `xs:integer` instead of the default `xs:double` (`number`), you could also consider the use of `format-number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Martin's comment, the `number()` function converts to an `xs:double`, and the default output format for `xs:double` is scientific notation for values outside the range 1e-6 to 1e6.

You could either do the arithmetic in `xs:decimal` instead of `xs:double`, by using the `xs:decimal()` function in place of `number()`, or you could override the way `xs:double` values are formatted by using the `format-number()` function.

Incidentally the call to `number()` in `number($intTotal)` is redundant because the value is already an `xs:double`. And it's always a good idea to declare the types of your variables with an `as` attribute so it's clear to the reader what's going on.